# Donations Made with False Name and Address using Paypal WPP

Tags: civicontribute

A Membership payment was made successfully using our Contribute form with a new contact created such as:

name: fffff fffff

address:
asdadad 4
davie, FL 33328
United States

email:

jdchjffdjhf@gmail.com

Contribution says paid by Credit Card, and there is also a transaction/invoice ID.

Why is CiviCRM Paypal WPP processor allowing this contribution which obviously appears to be fraudulent? Is this due to our set up

Thank you.

Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 4.6.x

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain what can be done to stop people 'testing' if stolen credit card details if that is what is happening. There is a [blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/xcf33/civicrm-flood-control-use-case-and-implementation) about it and an old [forum topic](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=19243.0) you might glean something from

And this [SE question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/how-to-prevent-fraud-attempts-on-contribution-pages) is where the conversation moved to.

Comment: Thanks. What's alarming is it happened within the same week for two installs on separate sites, its almost like Civi is being targeted for this testing. Does a CAPTCHA on the registration form prevent this - do you think they are mostly drive-by's done by automated scripts?

Comment: reCaptcha on sites helps to prevent spambots. Are the sites receiving the money? Wild guesses: perhaps there is some attempt to defraud PayPal going on if you are not getting the money or if a refund is immediately requested, or perhaps there is an intent to verify the card number.

Comment: According to Paypal (we called) the fraudulent payments aren't covered by seller protection because we didn't require a shipping address. So we have to either keep the funds until something happens, or issue a refund (at our slight expense).

Comment: updated answer with link to other post about flood control

Comment: Does CiviCRM support anything like this for Paypal Website Payment Pro? https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing_CommandDriven/merchant/RiskControlsUpgrade-outside

Yes, it is being used on a couple of my sites to test stolen credit cards. The other posts aren't too helpful because I don't believe it is a drive-by bot operation, but I have enabled captcha just in case.

Comment: Check https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors

Answer (score 2):

PayPal also offers some fraud filters. There's a decent starting set that come with PayPal Pro (they also offer more advanced ones for a monthly fee), their customer service is pretty good if you call and ask for some help with them and explain about the transactions you suspect are fraudulent.